# Visual Studio 2010 create project with the same name and location that old removed project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created project in visual studio that had a wrong type of project. So I decided to remove it and create different type of project but with the same name and location in the solution. Visual Studio shows message:

The project directory already exists. When a project is created, it must be placed within a new folder of the same name. Choose a different name or location for your project.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Delete the old folder from `C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects` and `Backup Files`

Comment: Thanks I did not realize at first that visual studio adds projects to the subfolder in solution but to main solution folder. That's why I had problem detecting it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigate to the folder on the file system and manually delete the old project directory.

Comment: I'd argue that the user shouldn't have to  do that. Why is that left behind after removing from the solution manager?

Comment: Remove != delete

Answer (score 1):

When you remove a project from a solution, it's not deleted, but the reference to the project.
So open the folder where the solution is located and delete the project folder.